# Нахождение множителей числа

Tags: алгоритм, php

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица "slim", в которой 2 столбика. Первое - code, второе - cx. Есть страница, в которой есть переменная $_num, которая равна определенному числу.

Как проверить, делится ли число $_num на все числа из столбика "cx" без остатка? Решается через цикл, но вот как именно - не соображу. 8-(

Подскажите, как это написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм таков:

1. запускаем цикл который обходит все значения $cx
2. делим в этом цикле $_num % $cx
3. если результат не равен 0 хоть одного результа деления делаем заключение о том что число $_num не
       делится без остатка на все числа из
       столбика cx

**%** в данном случае возвращает нам целочисленный остаток от деления $_num на $cx (т.е. 10 разделить на 5 вернет 0, а 10 разделить на 9 вернет 1).

Код таков:

```
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT `cx` FROM `slim`");
    while ($d = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $q ) )
    {
        extract ( $d );
        $rest = $_num % $d['cx'];
        if($rest!=0){$symmary=1;}
    }

    if($symmary==1)
    {
        echo 'Не делится';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Делится';
    }
```

Comment: так на словах и я согу, но вот работающий цикл получить не могу.

$total = /* кол - во записей в таблице */
$_num = /* число */ 

do
{ $nacalo = 1; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slim WHERE code = '$nacalo'",$db); $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result); $_a = $myrow['cx']; $_b = $_num / $_a; $_c = intval($_b); $_d = $_b - $_c; $q = 0; if ($_d == 0) { $q = $q + 1 ;} else {$q = $q + 0 ;} $nacalo = $nacalo + 1; $i = $i + 1; } while ($i < $total);

echo "$q";

Comment: Мьсье знает толк в извращениях, пример кода выше ;)

Comment: в таблице, в столбике cx значения 2,3. попробовал в новый код подставить в $_num числа 6 и 7, в обоих случаях = Не делится! т.е. код тоже с ошибкой 8-(

Comment: В цикле распечатку сделайте cx, _num и rest. Сразу станет понятно куда ошибка закралась. Скорее всего ошибка в получаемых или неполучаемых данных.